# Javascript SVG place arrow on bezier

Tags: javascript, svg, bezier

I have a cubic bezier. And I don't know how to put an arrow in the middle of it. Example below:

[image]

I want it to be like this, but with bezier. How can I do this.
Note: I've tried textPaths, markers. But nothing helped.

Comment: The example you show is definitely not a cubic bezier: do you have an SVG path, instead?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Position the marker(s), yourself, at the correct place
2. Split the line into two paths. One up to the first marker, and one for the rest of the path.  Then assign an end marker on each path.

Comment: ad 2: it can remain one path if it has a vertex in the midlle and a `marker-mid` (plus a `marker-end`).

Comment: Yes, @ccprog is correct. If you can make your path using only three points, you can assign a mid marker to get an arrow on the "middle" point.  I didn't bother mentioning that approach in my answer, because paths like your pictured example cannot be constructed using only three points.

Answer (score 2):

### #1 Solution

I thank @Paul LeBeau, who found a solution and below the implementation:

- We make two patches: a straight line and a curve at the end of which
  there will also be markers.

  `<path id="line_Path" d="m20.8 22.9c0 0 47.7-0.3 68.9-0.1" /> 
  <path id="curve_Path" d="m89.5 22.9c0 0 7.3 0 7.3 6.5 0 24 0 65.4 0 65.4 0
  0-2.5 7.6 7.1 7.6 29.6 0 77.5 0 77.5 0l0 0"/>`
- For accurate positioning of the marker, the following attributes are
  used: `refX="10"`, `refY="5"`

```html
<svg  width="200" height="120" viewBox="0 0 200 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
<defs>
<marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="10" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10">
<polyline points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red"/>
</marker>
</defs>
<style>
#line_Path, #curve_Path {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:2;
marker-end:url(#MarkerArrow);
}
</style>

<path id="line_Path" d="m20.8 22.9c0 0 47.7-0.3 68.9-0.1" />
<path id="curve_Path" d="m89.5 22.9c0 0 7.3 0 7.3 6.5 0 24 0 65.4 0 65.4 0 0-2.5 7.6 7.1 7.6 29.6 0 77.5 0 77.5 0l0 0"/> 

</svg>
```

### #2 Solution

- You can draw an arrow as an independent object

  `<polyline id="MarkerArrow" points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red"/>`
- And place it on the curve the required number of times with the help
  of the command

  `<use xlink:href="#MarkerArrow" x="80" y="18"/>`

```html
<svg  width="200" height="120" viewBox="0 0 200 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
<defs>
<polyline id="MarkerArrow" points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red"/>
</defs>
<path d="m20.8 22.9c0 0 47.7-0.3 68.9-0.1 5.4 0 6.8 2.9 6.9 6.8 0.4 22.6-0.8 45.9 0 66.6 0.2 4.2 2.6 6.5 6.6 6.6C129.1 103.1 180 102.2 180 102.2l0.7 0.5"   style="  fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width:2; "/>  

<use xlink:href="#MarkerArrow" x="80" y="18"/>
<use xlink:href="#MarkerArrow" x="178" y="97"/>

</svg>
```